# Async script in python runs fully time

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await

How can I run a/the following script asyncron so that it always runs and you can add arguments so that a new thread is always created, so to speak.

Example Script

```
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def home():
    return {"Data": "Test"}


@app.get("/live-check/")
async def live_check(response: Response):
    response.headers["Status"] = "OK"
    return "live check successful"


@app.get("/get-latest-file-user/", status_code=200)
async def show_file()
...
```

My test-script:

```py
def get_config():
    '''get the arguments'''

    config_object = ConfigParser()
    try:
       ...
    except KeyError:
        print("INI File not found!")
        quit()

def main(conf_args: dict):
    '''main function - Controlling and starting of most functions'''

    serialNumber = get_serial(conf_args['cert'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf_args = get_args(DictIni)               #Get Input(args)
    main(conf_args)
```

Can anyone transfer it to this?

The script makes no sense I know, I just want to understand the principle.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain in more detail what it is you want to do? I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: Just need an example script which runs fully time, where you can add arguments in terminal and it is processing it with a thread and not with starting the programm, I think this is faster